# MATLAB gui: Execute code before CreateFcns

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'd like to execute some code before the CreateFcns are called (e.g. from textbox, pop menus etc), because my CreateFcns rely on some struct data, which that specific code would fill in.

It seems that the functions are called in that order:

```
- CreateFcn 1
- Init Fcn
- CreateFcn 2
- Init Fcn
...
- CreateFcn n
- Init Fcn
- OpeningFcn
- Init Fcn
```

Is there a way to execute some code before the first CreateFcn? As the newest CreateFcn is called always first, the workaround to put the code in the first CreateFcn is extremely unhandy as you need to change the code everytime you add a new textbox etc. to the gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure containing the controls also has a `CreateFcn`. This is called before the `CreateFcn`s for the child control.

Ensure GUIDE has generated and assigned a `CreateFcn` to the figure by right-clicking the figure background and choosing *View Callbacks > CreateFcn*. Any initialization code depended on by the child controls should be added to this function.

Comment: Do you have any literature about that function? There is none in the code which was generated by the Matlab GUIDE.

Comment: Not all callbacks for all graphics elements (including the figure) are created when you create the element in GUIDE. New callbacks are created and added to the code the first time you select a callback under the "View Callbacks" menu for that element.

Answer (score 0):

As @Will pointed out correctly, the right way is to write the code in the create function of the figure itself as this one is always called first.

Just add this to the code

```
function figure1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% Code here will be executed first before all other functions
```

Comment: You can't just add a function with that name! The actual `CreateFcn` property of the figure needs to be set with a reference to the function for it to be called. GUIDE creates this reference as well as the function in the code when you first select that callback under "View Callbacks".

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I did it the way as you suggested but I thought it's the same if you just copy that function in your code.